# Umbraco 11 get current page in block grid item component

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am creating a component to add to a block grid so I have the following razor page cshtml

```cshtml
@using Umbraco.Extensions
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Views.UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.Blocks.BlockGridItem>

@{
    string title = Model.Content.Value<string>("Title");
    string subTitle = Model.Content.Value<string>("SubTitle");
    string alignment = Model.Content.Value<string>("Alignment");
    var image = Model.Content.Value<IPublishedContent>("BackgroundImage");
    string imageUrl = image != null ? Umbraco.Media(image.Id).Url() : "/image/upload/no-image_bucaqf.png";

    string modifier = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alignment) ? $"simple-banner__content--{alignment.ToLower()}" : string.Empty;
}


<div class="simple-banner">
    <img src="@imageUrl" alt="@title" class="simple-banner__image" />
    <div class="simple-banner__content @modifier">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            <h2 class="simple-banner__title">@title</h2>
        }
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subTitle))
        {
            <h3 class="simple-banner__subtitle">@subTitle</h3>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

This all works fine but I want to get some values from the current page the component is added to.  How do I get the `IPublishedContent` object of the current page from inside my component?

I have tried the following but most throws errors of one kind or another:

```
UmbracoContext.Current  // current is not a property of umbraco context
Umbraco.AssignedContentItem // Cannot return the IPublishedContent because the UmbracoHelper was not constructed with an IPublishedContent.
UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest.PublishedContent // Published request is null
```

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco, you can access the IPublishedContent of the current page from within your Razor component. Use the UmbracoHelper to retrieve it.

But, you do need to have access to the UmbracoHelper within your Razor component, which you can do by injecting UmbracoHelper into your Razor component.

Do this by using the @inject directive.

c# code

```
@using Umbraco.Extensions
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Views.UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.Blocks.BlockGridItem>
@inject UmbracoHelper Umbraco

@{
    // Your existing code
    string title = Model.Content.Value<string>("Title");
    string subTitle = Model.Content.Value<string>("SubTitle");
    string alignment = Model.Content.Value<string>("Alignment");
    var image = Model.Content.Value<IPublishedContent>("BackgroundImage");
    string imageUrl = image != null ? Umbraco.Media(image.Id).Url() : "/image/upload/no-image_bucaqf.png";

    string modifier = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(alignment) ? $"simple-banner__content--{alignment.ToLower()}" : string.Empty;
}

<!-- Your HTML content -->
```

By injecting UmbracoHelper, you can access the IPublishedContent as you need to.

C# code

```
var currentPage = Umbraco.Content(UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest.PublishedContent.Id);
```

Hopefully by now, you can access the IPublishedContent of the current page.

Carry out normal checks e.g. for null returns etc.

Comment: As stated above, my `UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest` is null so this just throws a null exception when trying to get `UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest.PublishedContent.Id` - `UmbracoContext.PublishedRequest.PublishedContent` would also be the current page in that situation so not sure why you would need the helper to re-get the page using the id